# The very first implementation of STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am very interested in seeing the very first implementation of C++ Standard Template Library. Well, it is for historical reasons. I am curious to see how the library evolved throughout the time.

What is the first version (implementation) of STL that is officially available? When and where it was published? How can I get it?

Comment: Are you aware that the STL and the C++ standard library are two distinct things? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/395760

Answer (score 2):

You can follow along with the development of Stepanov's thinking on generic programming at the site he's set up to collect his papers:

http://www.stepanovpapers.com/